# Get position of all finger when the screen is touched

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, swift3, touchscreen

I'd like to create my own gesture recognizer, and to create a kind of pinch & zoom I'd like to get position of all fingers at any moment.

Right now I'm able to track a finger with :

```
var countTouch:[Int] = []
var rawPoints:[Int] = []

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if(rawPoints[rawPoints.count-2] != Int(location.x) && rawPoints[rawPoints.count-1] != Int(location.y)) {
        rawPoints.append(Int(location.x))
        rawPoints.append(Int(location.y))
    }
}
```

And to know how many fingers are touching the screen at the moment with :

```
    super.touchesMoved(touches, 
    countTouch.append((event?.allTouches?.count)!)
```

But I don't know where all the data about position of the other fingers are going.

Can someone help on this please ?

Comment: The `Set<UITouch>` includes a `UITouch` for each finger. Each `UITouch` has a `location(in:)` method to get it's location in a view. it's unclear what part you're having trouble with.

Comment: @RobNapier My trouble is to get the position of each finger. How to access it ? Is it an array where I just have to do [finger#x][x position] ? Or something else. I don't understand how it works for multiple touches. Is it clearer ?

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/a/39823992/7113238 might be helpful for you.

Comment: Ok,  it looks like it's working. 
Make an answer with the code and a link to the previous answer, and I'll mark you as the correct answer :)
Thank you for your answer.